# Merging two different Plots in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to merge two plot in only one graph in R ,but i stuck how to accomplish it

First plot :

```
     plot_1 <- plot(serie_2,dt_frame$students,main="Plot 1",col=1,pch=19)
```

Second Plot :

```
      plot_2 <- plot(serie_3,dt_frame$numbers,main="Plot 2",col=5,pch=19)
```

How can i show these separate plots in one plot

Comment: does `plot(serie_3,dt_frame$numbers,main="Plot 2",col=5,pch=19, add = TRUE)` work?

Comment: @Wimpel nope :(

Comment: @Wimpel it says that "add" is not a graphical parameter

Comment: Then pease add a minimal sample of the data used in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
 geom_point(aes(x=serie_2, y=dt_frame$students, col="blue")) +
 geom_point(aes(x=serie_3, y=dt_frame$numbers, col="red")) +
 labs(x = "Student", y = "Grade") +
 scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red"),
                    labels=c("Series 2", "Series 3"))
```

Comment: When i use it , how can i name x-axis as student and y-axis as grade ? Moreover , i want to indicate that blue represent series 2 and red is for series 3

Comment: I recommend you learn a bit about ggplot2. Start with this cheatsheet: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/main/data-visualization.pdf ; I will edit my answer for your specific question

Comment: thanks for help , because of my low reputation , i could not upvote